# Can't read Mahout generated sequence files with hadoop streaming

Tags: mahout, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to stream a sequence file generated by one of the Mahout examples to see its contents:

```
    hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u0.jar \
    -input /tmp/mahout-work-me/20news-bydate/bayes-test-input-output/ \
    -output /tmp/me/mm \
    -mapper "cat" \
    -reducer "wc -l" \
    -inputformat SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat
```

The job starts successfully and eventually dies with:

```
11/11/30 21:08:39 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
11/11/30 21:09:17 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: org.apache.mahout.common.StringTuple
```

I wonder if something is wrong with my streaming jar file, if I I need to point explicitly to the Mahout jar that has this class (tried setting HADOOP_CLASSPATH to the location of mahout-core-0.5-cdh3u2.jar but did not work), or maybe even something else?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out. 
Providing the following option: -libjars ~/mahout-0.5-cdh3u2/mahout-core-0.5-cdh3u2.jar to the command solved the problem:

        hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u0.jar \
        -libjars ~/mahout-0.5-cdh3u2/mahout-core-0.5-cdh3u2.jar \
        -input /tmp/mahout-work-me/20news-bydate/bayes-test-input-output/ \
        -output /tmp/me/mm \
        -mapper "cat" \
        -reducer "wc -l" \
        -inputformat SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this option:

```
-libjars mahout-core-0.5-cdh3u2.jar
```